# Yii2 Invalid Configuration The directory does not exist: ___ Windows 11

Tags: php, yii2

При разветывание Yii2 ловлю ошибку. Но какой папки не хватает? Мб в правах дела?

Перепробовал многое, но ни как не хочет запускаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: либо нет папки web/assets либо на неё нет прав

Comment: магия винды какая-то случилась. Права слетали. Так что да, вы правы оказались. Тогда, если хотите, напишите ответ, отмечу как верный и закроем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная ошибка возникает в двух (известных мне) случаях:

1. Нет папки `web/assets`
2. Нет прав на папку `web/assets`

Необходимо проверить оба этих пункта и исправить